How to prevent division before multiplication precision loss?
In the else statement, where the Boolean is false, the amount has more than 18 decimals. In this example I used a 24 decimal amount, 123456789123456789123456. Now, it will return 123456789123456789. How do I prevent the precision loss?
Source: https://calnix.gitbook.io/eth-dev/yield-mentorship-2022/projects/5-collateralized-vault/pricing-+-decimal-scaling
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract precision {
    
    function standardize(uint256 amount, bool true_less_false_more) external pure returns (uint256 standardizedAmount) {
        standardizedAmount = amount;
        if (true_less_false_more) { 
            standardizedAmount *= 10 ** (18 - 6); //123456
        } 
        else if (!true_less_false_more) { 
            standardizedAmount /= 10 ** (24 - 18); //123456789123456789123456 
            // standardizedAmount = 123456789123456789123456 / 1e6;
            // standardizedAmount = 123456789123456789 (Last six decimals will be truncated)
        }
    }
}


Last six decimals are getting truncated because you're converting it from 24-decimal format to 18-decimal format explicitly in your else condition. What exactly you want to achieve?

I want to keep the last 6 decimals too. Is there a way to downscale without losing precision?

In such a scenario, there's no need to downscale; instead, you need to upscale the other value (having lower decimal precision) with which you're multiplying or dividing.

If you want to keep the last 6 decimals, then it's not actually downscaling from 24-decimal format to 18-decimal format, instead it's keeping it the same. And that, you can simply achieve by getting rid of your else condition completely.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract precision {
    
    function standardize(uint256 amount, bool true_less_false_more) external pure returns (uint256 standardizedAmount) {
        standardizedAmount = amount;
        if (true_less_false_more) { 
            standardizedAmount *= 10 ** (18 - 6); 
        } 
        // else { 
        //     // Do nothing
        // }
    }
}

P.S., In such a scenario, there's no need to downscale; instead, you need to upscale the other value (having lower decimal precision) with which you're multiplying or dividing.

Thanks I think there is no reason to downscale.
